# C++ initialize static map of objects

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a map of static objects `map<string, base*>`, where `base` is derived by classes `class1` and `class2`. My map will store pointers to objects of type `class1` and `class2`.

After reading a few posts I decided to do this by creating a singleton with a static class function to initialize the map:

```
class A {  // singleton class
public:

static map<string, base*> create_map() {
map<string,base*> m;
m["1"]=new class1();
m["2"]=new class2();
};
static const map<string, base*> myMap;
};

int main() {    
const map<string,base*> A::myMap = A::create_map();
myMap["1"]->func();    
}
```

However this gives an error: `myMap is not declared in this scope`. Can somebody explain the singleton method and what I am doing wrong. How would this change if I have a separate header file ?
TIA.

EDIT:
Changed the code to:

```
class A {  // singleton class
public:

static map<string, base*> create_map() {
map<string,base*> m;
m["1"]=new class1();
m["2"]=new class2();
return m;
};
static const map<string, base*> myMap;
};

const map<string,base*> A::myMap = A::create_map();
int main() {    

A::myMap["1"]->func();    
}
```

This still gives an error: `passing const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, base*> as 'this' discards qualifiers.`

Comment: Regarding singletons: why do you need one? What about simply calling your function only once (and passing it a reference to the map)?

Comment: create_map() returns map<string, base*> you dont return anything... am I missing something? where `m`  is declared on the stack and gets destroyed at the end of your `create_maps` scope

Comment: Also note that 1. the `create_map` function doesn't return the created map. 2. You are leaking memory because of using raw pointers. Using `std::unique_ptr` will solve that. Arguably it's not too bad here, because the leak happens when your program exits, so the OS will clean it up, but still.

Comment: `const map<string,base*> A::myMap = A::create_map();` should be outside of `main`

Comment: @Darhuuk : can you please give an example of what you mean when you say 'simply calling your function' ?

Comment: If your `map` is `const`, use `.at("1")` instead of `["1"]`.

Comment: @Jagadeesh Well, instead of trying to enforce that you have a singleton, how about just creating the object once? Does that make your code easier? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the line `map<string, base*> A::myMap;` after your class.
You should also avoid the const declaration of your map object, and create_map() method was lacking of a return statement

```
class A {  // singleton class
public:

    static map<string, base*> create_map() {
        map<string,base*> m;
        m["1"] = new class1();
        m["2"] = new class2();

        return m;
    }

    static map<string, base*> myMap;
};

map<string, base*> A::myMap;

int main() {
    A::myMap = A::create_map();
    A::myMap["1"]->func();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

myMap is a member of A, you need to address it accordingly.

```
A::myMap["1"]->func();
```